# Django 4.0 wildcard subdomain preventing from setting csrf token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, subdomain, csrf, django-csrf

I'm having a problem with Django 4.0 backend in debug mode where I use session auth with csrf token.

I use wildcard subdomains:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://*.local.lab:8080"]
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".local.lab"]
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

When I'm accessing app on http://local.lab:8080 CSRF token is being sent and set in browser storage, all works as intended.

When I'm accessing app with any other URL combination i.e. http://www.local.lab:8080 or http://subdomain.local.lab:8080 CSRF request comes back with the correct cookie but the cookie is never set in a browsers storage and that prevents me from creating x-csrf token and making any post requests.

Everything I'm testing on local domain where I mapped my local IP to the domain local.lab with help of the tool dnsmasq.

What am I doing wrong in here?